# Is $\overline{A}$ path-connected?

Tags: general-topology

**True/False**

If $A\subset X$ is path-connected, then $\overline{A}$ is path-connected.

Any hints would be much appreciated; I'm not looking for a full solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Take the graph of $\sin\frac1x, \ x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's false, the famous *closed topologist's sine curve* shows why.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve#Variants .